# Identify Request object for currently arrived Response restkit v0.20

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restkit

I am making two post calls to same service how to identify the response that arrived with its respective request.

```
req1 = post {"status" = "1"} 
req2 = post {"status" = "0"}

response {"data" = "xxx"}
response {"data" = "yyy"}
```

how to identify which response is for req1 and req2.
i am using restkit v0.20.

```
-(void)fetchCoursesWithToken:(NSString *)token  courseType:(NSInteger)courseType{
AppSettings *settings = [AppSettings sharedAppSettings];
NSString *userCourseServiceURL = settings.getCoursesURL;

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

[settings showActivityIndicatorWithMessage:@""];



CourseRequest *reqObj = [CourseRequest new];
reqObj.loginToken = token;
reqObj.courseType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",courseType];







RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:reqObj method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:userCourseServiceURL parameters: nil];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [settings removeActivityIndicator];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = [[operation HTTPRequestOperation] response]; //operation is an RKObjectRequestOperation

    NSDictionary *headerDictionary = [response allHeaderFields];

    NSString *status = [headerDictionary objectForKey:@"X-NTST-Request-Status"];

    if ([status isEqualToString:@"ERR"]) {
        NSString *errorMessage = [headerDictionary objectForKey:@"X-NTST-Request-Note"];
        NSLog(@"Error Occured :%@",errorMessage);
    }
    else if ([status isEqualToString:@"WARN"]) {
        NSString *errorMessage = [headerDictionary objectForKey:@"X-NTST-Request-Note"];
        NSLog(@"Error Occured :%@",errorMessage);
    }
    if ([status isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        NSLog(@"Succes status:%@",status);
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[mappingResult array]];
        [self.delegate responseArrived:arr];
    }



} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);
    [settings removeActivityIndicator];
}];
[RKObjectManager.sharedManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
 }
```

I am making call to the same function 
from View controller

```
 [self.service fetchCoursesWithToken:@"ds"    courseType:0 ];


[self.service fetchCoursesWithToken:@"ds"    courseType:1 ];
```

when response arrives I have callback delegate to view controller.
since i am using same function response call back to same block.

Comment: create two connections for both post and put response in if else condition

Comment: you can also use blocks to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restkit is block-based, therefore when you make a request you can pass a block (actually two, one for success and one for failure) to be executed when the response comes.

Since the blocks are associated with the individual requests, there's not need to discriminate.

Comment: yes , but i am having same block for both the response since request is made to same service with different param value in request body

Comment: if you need to perform two different actions, just pass two different blocks